# Showing the scaling $\omega \sim \frac{t^{n+1}}{n}$ graphically.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions

Suppose $\omega$ scales as $t^{n}$, where $t$ is a constant and $n \in \Bbb{Z}^{+}$.

In order to show it graphically, we can consider the ratio $\frac{\omega_{n+1}}{\omega_{n}}$ and it is equal to the constant $t$. So when we plot $\frac{\omega_{n+1}}{\omega_{n}}$ vs $n$ it gives us a sequence of points converging to the straight line parallel to the $n$-axis (joining the discrete points).

But this gets tricky if $\omega$ scales as $\frac{t^{n+1}}{n}$ as then $\frac{\omega_{n+1}}{\omega_{n}}$ equals something not a constant and hence not easy to interpret or prove graphically. Any ideas?

Comment: With "scales to" do you mein $$\omega_n=const*a^n? \text{ and in the second case  } const*\frac{a^n}{n-1}$$ then you become a curve like n-1/n

Comment: Yes exactly! Thanks, but I am thinking of a  way to show it by some convergence, like in the above first case, the points would slowly start to converge to the straight line $\frac{\omega_{n+1}}{\omega_{n}}=t$, but this gets tricky when $\omega \sim \frac{t^{n+1}}{n}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not look at $n\omega_n\sim t^n$ and thus

$$\frac{(n+1)\omega_{n+1}}{n\omega_n}\to t$$

which should tend to a straight line as well.

Comment: That's a good idea (as we only need to handle the denominator)!